# объединение всех значений столбца в одну ячейку

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить объединение значений

исходная таблица типа:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| x | (1,2,3) |
| x | (4,5,6) |
| x | (7,8,9) |

в итоге нужно получить

```
x    | (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

на самом деле таблица полигонов, нужно сделать в итоге что-то типа мультиполигональной

буду признательна за любую помощь/подсказку/направление

Comment: ну вы хоть бы написали, какой библиотекой пользуетесь. pandas, надеюсь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["x", "x", "x"], "value":[(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]})
```

```
  name      value
0    x  (1, 2, 3)
1    x  (4, 5, 6)
2    x  (7, 8, 9)
```

то, достаточно просто сделать группировку с суммированием:

```
res = df.groupby("name", as_index=False).sum()
```

res:

```
 name                        value
0    x  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```